# from cmd import Cmd, (not working with class MyPrompt)

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, inner-classes

This is a helper command line in python, I was looking to add custom stuff for myself of course and was adding in a IP searcher. Have been getting this error for a while now, cant seem to figure it out and its critical to start my prompt. Any Tips appreciated, Good day.

```
from cmd import Cmd
import pyautogui as pag #Future#
import time #Debugging/Future#
import sys,os
clear = lambda : os.system('cls')
#############################################
from colorama import init
from ctypes.test.test_pickling import name
init(strip=not sys.stdout.isatty()) # strip colors if stdout is redirected
from termcolor import cprint 
from pyfiglet import figlet_format
##############################################

class MyPrompt(Cmd):

    @staticmethod
    def do_lineage(self):
        """Switch to Lineage 2 Helper"""
        print("Switching to Lineage 2 Helper....")
        os.system(r"python C:\Users\David\eclipse-workspace\CMD\src\L2.py")

    @staticmethod
    def do_ip(self):
        """IP"""
        print("Switching to IP stuff.... ")
        os.system(r"python C:\Users\David\eclipse-workspace\CMD\src\Play.py")    

    @staticmethod
    def do_quit(self):
        """Quits the program."""
        print("Quitting...")
        raise SystemExit

    @staticmethod
    def do_Movies(self,num):
        """1-3 different sites, or all for """
        if num == 1:
            print("https://genvideos.org")
            os.system("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome --app=https://genvideos.org")
        if num == 2:
            print("https://www3.gomovies.sc")
            os.system("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome --app=https://www3.gomovies.sc")
        if num == 3:
            print("https://vioozgo.org/")
            os.system("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome --app=google.com")
        if num == "all":
            print("https://genvideos.org")
            print("https://www3.gomovies.sc")
            print("https://vioozgo.org/")
            os.system("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome --app=google.com")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    clear()
    prompt = MyPrompt()
    prompt.prompt = '> '
    prompt.cmdloop(cprint(figlet_format('--------\nHelper\n--------', font='smslant'), "yellow"))
```

My error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David\eclipse-workspace\CMD\src\Cmdd.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cmd import Cmd
ImportError: cannot import name 'Cmd'
```

This was previously working, must of changed something. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You have some other module called `cmd` that Python is finding instead of the built-in one.

Comment: @kindall I cant seem to find this cmd. I've created a separate file to test the basics, doesn't seem like the Cmd subclass of cmd can be imported. Strange...

Comment: Thanks @kindall - in my case, I was running some test code I found on Code Maven, and stupidly named my test file "cmd.py". Once I renamed the file to something else it ran fine.

Answer (score 1):

When I encounter an issue like this, I like drop myself into a debugger in the command line and start poking around.

To do this, I add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` near where the issue is happening, in this case at the top of the file.  Once in debug mode, I starting looking at the object that is causing the issue. I'd probably start with changing the import statement to import the full `cmd` module, and then I would `dir` said module.  You can print `cmd.__file__` to see where it is coming from

```
import cmd
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
# code stops here so you can start digging
# dir(cmd) will tell you what properties the module has
# cmd.__file__ will tell you the file path

from cmd import Cmd
import pyautogui as pag #Future#
import time #Debugging/Future#
import sys,os
clear = lambda : os.system('cls')
#############################################
from colorama import init
from ctypes.test.test_pickling import name
init(strip=not sys.stdout.isatty()) # strip colors if stdout is redirected
from termcolor import cprint 
from pyfiglet import figlet_format
##############################################

class MyPrompt(Cmd):

    @staticmethod
    def do_lineage(self):
        """Switch to Lineage 2 Helper"""
        print("Switching to Lineage 2 Helper....")
        os.system(r"python C:\Users\David\eclipse-workspace\CMD\src\L2.py")

    @staticmethod
    def do_ip(self):
        """IP"""
        print("Switching to IP stuff.... ")
        os.system(r"python C:\Users\David\eclipse-workspace\CMD\src\Play.py")    

    @staticmethod
    def do_quit(self):
        """Quits the program."""
        print("Quitting...")
        raise SystemExit

    @staticmethod
    def do_Movies(self,num):
        """1-3 different sites, or all for """
        if num == 1:
            print("https://genvideos.org")
            os.system("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome --app=https://genvideos.org")
        if num == 2:
            print("https://www3.gomovies.sc")
            os.system("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome --app=https://www3.gomovies.sc")
        if num == 3:
            print("https://vioozgo.org/")
            os.system("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome --app=google.com")
        if num == "all":
            print("https://genvideos.org")
            print("https://www3.gomovies.sc")
            print("https://vioozgo.org/")
            os.system("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome --app=google.com")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    clear()
    prompt = MyPrompt()
    prompt.prompt = '> '
    prompt.cmdloop(cprint(figlet_format('--------\nHelper\n--------', font='smslant'), "yellow"))
```